# keycloak: realistic operating costs

Tags: keycloak, identity-management, cost-management

I am facing the decision to host keycloak myself as IAM for a multitenant SaaS or to use a cloud IAM like AWS Cognito / Google Identity Platform.

To be able to compare the costs, I would need to know how much it costs to run Keycloak professionally - i.e. with high availability, monitoring, maintenance, backups, etc.

Does anyone have concrete, experience based values for this?

For example, for a scenario with 50k / 100k / 200k / 500k monthly active users and 100 / 500 / 1000 tenants (= realms) -
How many resources does the deployment need, how many staff hours for the operation etc.?

That would be very helpful, thank you!

Comment: The cost will likely be driven by (1) cost of trained staff for setup and on duty 24 x 7 and (3) hardware and software for high availability, monitoring and backup. The number of active users and realms won't matter much.